# 3.5mm jack with GL driver

Tags: driver

I've installed the GL driver (with full KMS) on my Raspberry Pi 3, but now it doesn't output to the 3.5mm jack, except for the rainbow screen. How could I get the GL driver to output to the 3.5mm jack?